# How to use ICMP to send message

Tags: ping, icmp, pcap

I was trying to send ICMP package with Payload/Message on server_A to server_B(10.1.1.5) as following:
`ping -p 12345 10.1.1.5`.

but when I use Tcpdump to capture the ICMP package from server_A, I didn't see any message(it should be 12345). 
How can I get the icmp payload please?

Comment: Different implementations of the ping application can do things differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ping` doesn't send user messages. It generates an *ICMP Echo Request* that the destination is supposed to answer with an *ICMP Echo Reply*.

Echo requests use a dummy payload data encapsulated within the packet. `-p` allows you to specify hte content of that payload with some `ping` versions. `-p 12345` fills the payload with 0x012345 bytes repetitively for the specified length (`-s` parameter for Linux). The echo reply returns the dummy payload if working correctly.

For details, see [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792) page 14.